# easy_thumbnail does not show image

Tags: python, django, image, thumbnails

I have a blog model

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    photo = models.ForeignKey('testApp.Media',blank=True,null=True)
```

then I create a blog object in view

```
def posts(requests):
    recents = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-date')[0:3]
    return render(request,"abc.html",{'posts':posts})
```

then I use recents object in my abc.html template like:

```
{% for recent in recents %}
      <li class="clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left blg-img">
      <img src="{{ recent.photo.file |thumbnail_url:'smallpost'}}" alt="" />
      </div>
        <div class="pull-left blg-txt">
          <p><a href="{% url 'detail' recent.slug %}">{{recent.title}}</a></p>
          <div class="sidebar-blg-date">{{recent.date}}</div>
        </div>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
```

I load thumbnail at the top in my html file and my settings

```
THUMBNAIL_ALIASES = {
    '': {
        'bigpost': {'size': (250, 200), 'crop': "scale"},
        'smallpost': {'size':(70,50),'crop':True},
    },
}
```

I install libjpeg pillow pil and easythumbnail 
my problem is when I use thumbnail_url:"smallpost" the image is disappeared

I cant find solution anywhere.

Comment: do you load the thumbnail template tag?
`{% load thumbnail %}` at the top of your template

Comment: yes I wrote it at the top

Comment: When you installed PIL did you check the setup summary? `JPEG support available` etc